# Output of the select with join query result data in treeview

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, treeview, pymysql

First of all, I want to apologize for my level of English and programming.
The problem lies in the output of data in the treeview module of the results of the select with join query. As you can see in the picture, the data output is recorded in only one column. I need to break them further into the following columns
Thank you for your time!
P/s I read the approximate previously asked questions but could not find an answer.

```
 from tkinter import *
import pymysql
import tkinter as tk
from settings import host, user, password, db_name
from tkinter import ttk


try:
    connection = pymysql.connect(
        host=host,
        port=3306,
        user=user,
        password=password,
        database=db_name,
        cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
    )
    print("successfully connected ...")
    print (20*"#")

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Petproject1")
    root.geometry = ("1550x800+0+0")

    tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=("column1", "column2", "column3", "column4"))
    tree.heading("#0", text="Index")
    tree.heading("column1", text="Operator")
    tree.heading("column2", text="Main radiostation")
    tree.heading("column3", text="subordinate radiostation")
    tree.heading("column4", text="subordinate radiostation")
    tree.column("#0", width=50, minwidth=50, stretch=tk.NO)
    tree.column("column1", width=500, minwidth=500, stretch=tk.NO)
    tree.column("column2", width=200, minwidth=200, stretch=tk.NO)
    tree.column("column3", width=200, minwidth=200, stretch=tk.NO)
    tree.column("column4", width=200, minwidth=200, stretch=tk.NO)

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        query_join2 = "SELECT operator.first_name, unit.name, u.name, u2.name FROM betawork\
              INNER JOIN operator ON betawork.id_operator = operator.id\
              INNER JOIN unit ON betawork.main_RS = unit.id_unit \
              LEFT JOIN unit u ON betawork.sub_RS1 = u.id_unit \
              LEFT JOIN unit u2 ON betawork.sub_RS2 = u2.id_unit"
        cursor.execute(query_join2)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()

        index = 0
        for row in rows:
            tree.insert("", index, text=str(index), values=row)
            index += 1

    tree.pack()
    root.mainloop()

except Exception as ex:
        print("Connection refused ...")
        print(ex)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcRtS.png)

I read documentation of pymysql, tkinter. Watched tutorial in youtube and asked friends who know programming.
I expect to solve my problem, and understand in which format (value) I get result of my select query in python

Comment: Do you want an actual "tree" or a "table"?  At the moment, you look like you are inserting all nodes as children of the _root_ by passing in `""` as the first parameter to `tree.insert()`

Comment: Thanks for your attention, first of all I want to display result of select in table view. If you can, please give me advice how to make it. And second, yes I writing like a child, cause I`m learning. Thank you for alloted time